# If $\prod _{n = 1 }^{\infty} a_n = 0$, then $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ or $\exists n$ : $a_n =0$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

I need to prove above(or contraposition) using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition. How can I do?

If $\prod _{n = 1 }^{\infty} a_n = 0$, then  $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ or $\exists  n$ : $a_n =0$?

Comment: What you can do is look for counter-examples. They are easy to find.

Comment: $\frac 12 \times \frac 12 \times \frac 12 \ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Another example is 
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-\frac1n)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}n=\frac12·\frac23·\frac34·\frac45···,$$ so that the factors converge to $1$.

There is a result that states that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-b_k)= 0\text{ where }b_k\in(0,1)
$$
if and only if 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k=\infty
$$